# Send the data from perftop to opensearch indices

Tags: opensearch, amazon-opensearch, opensearch-dashboards, opensearch-security-plugin, opensearchdescription

**Usecase : Send the output of perftop to opensearch indices.
**

I am using below commands to generate the perftop dashboards.

`./opensearch-perf-top-linux --dashboard ClusterOverview --endpoint http://127.0.0.1:9600`

This generates below output on the screen.

[image: opensearch-perf-top-dashboard]

Is there any way to store these information to opensearch.
My end goal is to create a monitoring dashboard?